# Log a user out of a SP but not IDP

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

Is it possible to log a user out of an application that uses SAML authentication, but keep them logged into the IDP so they can continue to access other service providers?

I want to be able to log a user out of an application, and have them authenticate when they return to the application without logging them out of the IDP (i.e. I don't want to use single sign out). Is this possible with SAML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no standard way to exclude termination of the IDP session when performing Single Logout. Also termination of a session with an individual session participant (a single Service Provider) while keeping the others opened is explicitly out of scope of the SAML 2.0 Single Logout profile (see saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf, lines 1139-1143). So that's not the way to go.

But there's another solution. You can use local logout at your service provider (e.g. simply invalidate local HTTP session) and combine it with attribute ForceAuthn when sending the AuthnRequest to the IDP (see saml-core-2.0-os, line 2042). Setting the ForceAuthn attribute to true forces the Identity Provider to authenticate user even in case when there's an existing IDP session.

The whole flow could look like this:

1. User accesses SP and is required to authenticate
2. SP sends an SAML 2.0 AuthnRequest to IDP and sets the ForceAuthn flag to true
3. IDP forces user to authenticate and responds to the SP
4. SP creates a local session after validating the response
5. User logs-out of the SP application which terminates only the local session and doesn't interfere with the IDP session or sessions at other SPs

Setting the ForceAuthn flag to true effectively disables single sign-on, so you might want to use some SP-side logic determining whether to use the flag or not.

An example of a valid request with the flag set follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceIndex="0"
    AttributeConsumingServiceIndex="myServiceID"
    Destination="https://idp.ssocircle.com:443/sso/SSOPOST/metaAlias/ssocircle"
    ForceAuthn="true" ID="a228aje276h0id1g48eihj5gfj9h8bi"
    IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2014-04-11T22:07:05.438Z"
    Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:test:sp</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

Comment: It's perfect buy my IdP is ignoring it.. Any help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281621/forceauthn-is-not-working-in-a-web-application