# SSO logout from Microsoft Account ever where, is it possible to logout only for specific Azure AD Enterprise application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

We Implemented SSO using .Net Core 6, ITfoxtec framework (https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2) and Azure AD Enterprise application. everything is working as expected, while logging out we use following code, which logged out user from Microsoft account and as result the user also logged off from other applications as well, can we log out user only for specific Azure AD enterprise application?

```
[HttpPost("Logout")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
return Redirect(Url.Content("~/"));
    }

var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
var saml2LogoutRequest = await new Saml2LogoutRequest(config, User).DeleteSession(HttpContext);
return **binding.Bind(saml2LogoutRequest).ToActionResult();** /* logged out from Microsoft application */
}
```

var saml2LogoutRequest = await new Saml2LogoutRequest(config, User).DeleteSession(HttpContext);
delete cookies as expected, our application does not have custom log in page, as soon as user hit webpage it will redirect user to log-in and because Azure AD session is still active it land user on home page. what we want is, once user logged out from the application and hit web page again it should ask to select Microsoft account to log-in.

```
[Route("Login")]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
{
var binding = new Saml2RedirectBinding();
    binding.SetRelayStateQuery(new Dictionary<string, string> 
        { { relayStateReturnUrl, returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/") } });

return binding.Bind(new Saml2AuthnRequest(config)).ToActionResult();
}
```

following is Azure AD Enterprise application SAML configuration

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of my knowledge a SAML 2.0 logout in an Azure Enterprice application result in a single logout including logging out of everything. I have not succeeded in only logging out of one application I’m afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this,
[Log a user out of a SP but not IDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021870/log-a-user-out-of-a-sp-but-not-idp) and as @Anders Revsgaard answered that SAML 2.0 does not support logout only from specific application, an other approach is to force IDP to re-authenticate,

once user logout from our application, delete user session which will in-validate user session, now next time when user try to access page he has to re-enter SSO credentials, **we removed** `binding.Bind(saml2LogoutRequest).ToActionResult();` from logout method.

```
[Route("Login")]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
{
  var binding = new Saml2RedirectBinding();
  binding.SetRelayStateQuery(new Dictionary<string, string> 
    {{ relayStateReturnUrl, returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/") }});
return binding.Bind(new Saml2AuthnRequest(config) {
                ForceAuthn = true,
            }).ToActionResult();
}

[HttpPost("Logout")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
  if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
      return Redirect(Url.Content("~/"));
   }

  var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
  var saml2LogoutRequest = await new Saml2LogoutRequest(config, 
  User).DeleteSession(HttpContext);
  return Redirect("~/Logout");
}
```

**ForceAuth = true** option is good when we want to re-authenticate user but every organization may not want to use this flow, because re-authentication is not seamless process, user has to enter credentials again and proceed further.

**To give seamless SSO log-in experience** to user, we can avoid ForceAuth = true and use below code which we offer to Pick an account and it will be re-direct to landing page of application.

```
 [Route("Login")]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        try
        {
            var binding = new Saml2RedirectBinding();
            binding.SetRelayStateQuery(new Dictionary<string, string> { { relayStateReturnUrl, returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/") } });                
            return binding.Bind(new Saml2AuthnRequest(config)
            {   
                NameIdPolicy = new NameIdPolicy { AllowCreate = true, Format = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" },                    
                RequestedAuthnContext = new RequestedAuthnContext
                {
                    Comparison = AuthnContextComparisonTypes.Exact,
                    AuthnContextClassRef = new string[] { AuthnContextClassTypes.PasswordProtectedTransport.OriginalString },
                },
            }).ToActionResult();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);                
        }
    }
```